# can't get a Scroll View to go vertical

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, scrollview

Iam currently making a resistor calculator app and have too many radio buttons in the radio group, so I wanted to add a scroll view to make it look nicer but the problem I have is I can't get it to go vertical

[image: layout]

I only added one Radio button in this post so the code wouldn't take up to much space.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="356dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.648"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.93">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroup3"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="386dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbBlack3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Black" />
 </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: replace `HorizontalScrollView` with ```ScrollView```

Comment: @Spiker working now thanks.